# How to print each records from database in new row?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have table called Parameters in which there is a field called

> parameters

Now

I select * from that table and fetch all the records.

So My Controller is like this:

```
$this->data['params'] = $this->parameter_m->get();
```

int the views i foreach through all the records.
 like this :

```
<tr>

    <td><?php foreach ($params as $param) {echo $param->parameter_name; }  ?></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

My Issue is that all data from parameters get displayed in the first `<tr>`, I want to display each parameters in separate `<tr>`

The parameters_name has some data, and I want that data in separate `<tr><td>Data1</td></tr> <td>Data2</td></tr>`
I hope you understood my issue.

The Array :

```
array (size=10)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[33]
      public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'parameter' => string 'SipUserName' (length=11)
      public 'parameter_name' => string 'SipUserName' (length=11)
      public 'in_type' => string 'readonly' (length=8)
      public 'is_mandatory' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'arg_1' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'arg_2' => string '' (length=0)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[34]
      public 'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'parameter' => string 'SipAuthName' (length=11)
      public 'parameter_name' => string 'SipAuthName' (length=11)
      public 'in_type' => string 'readonly' (length=8)
      public 'is_mandatory' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'arg_1' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'arg_2' => string '' (length=0)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[35]
      public 'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'parameter' => string 'DisplayName' (length=11)
      public 'parameter_name' => string 'DisplayName' (length=11)
      public 'in_type' => string 'readonly' (length=8)
      public 'is_mandatory' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'arg_1' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'arg_2' => string '' (length=0)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[36]
      public 'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      public 'parameter' => string 'Password' (length=8)
      public 'parameter_name' => string 'Password' (length=8)
      public 'in_type' => string 'readonly' (length=8)
      public 'is_mandatory' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'arg_1' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'arg_2' => string '' (length=0)
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[37]
      public 'id' => string '5' (length=1)
      public 'parameter' => string 'Domain' (length=6)
      public 'parameter_name' => string 'Domain' (length=6)
      public 'in_type' => string 'readonly' (length=8)
      public 'is_mandatory' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'arg_1' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'arg_2' => string '' (length=0)
  5 => 
    object(stdClass)[38]
      public 'id' => string '6' (length=1)
      public 'parameter' => string 'Proxy' (length=5)
      public 'parameter_name' => string 'Proxy' (length=5)
      public 'in_type' => string 'readonly' (length=8)
      public 'is_mandatory' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'arg_1' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'arg_2' => string '' (length=0)
  6 => 
    object(stdClass)[39]
      public 'id' => string '7' (length=1)
      public 'parameter' => string 'Port' (length=4)
      public 'parameter_name' => string 'Port' (length=4)
      public 'in_type' => string 'readonly' (length=8)
      public 'is_mandatory' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'arg_1' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'arg_2' => string '' (length=0)
  7 => 
    object(stdClass)[40]
      public 'id' => string '8' (length=1)
      public 'parameter' => string 'ServerMode' (length=10)
      public 'parameter_name' => string 'ServerMode' (length=10)
      public 'in_type' => string 'readonly' (length=8)
      public 'is_mandatory' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'arg_1' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'arg_2' => string '' (length=0)
  8 => 
    object(stdClass)[41]
      public 'id' => string '9' (length=1)
      public 'parameter' => string 'Param_1' (length=7)
      public 'parameter_name' => string 'Param_1' (length=7)
      public 'in_type' => string 'text' (length=4)
      public 'is_mandatory' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'arg_1' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'arg_2' => string '' (length=0)
  9 => 
    object(stdClass)[42]
      public 'id' => string '10' (length=2)
      public 'parameter' => string 'Param_2' (length=7)
      public 'parameter_name' => string 'Param_2' (length=7)
      public 'in_type' => string 'text' (length=4)
      public 'is_mandatory' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'arg_1' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'arg_2' => string '' (length=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should loop `<tr>` not `<td>` as below

```
<?php foreach($params as $param):?>
<tr>

    <td> <?php echo $param->parameter_name;?></td>

</tr>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: see this will give me: Data1Data2data3

Comment: have you opened the table?

Comment: can you post your $param array so that i can answer as per your requirement ??

Comment: what i want to do is that as you can see in array thier is parameter_name, i want print that in seprarte <tr><td>paramter_name</td>/<tr>

Comment: @Rajan did you try the answer that i have posted ?? Please update with the question with the actual array .

Comment: i have updated the actual array and i think it works let me just test it

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>parameter</td>
        <td>parameter_name</td>
        <td>in_type</td>
        <td>is_mandatory</td>
        <td>arg_1</td>
        <td>arg_2</td>
    </tr>
<?php
    foreach($params as $row){
        echo "  <tr>";
        echo "      <td>" . $row->id . "</td>";
        echo "      <td>" . $row->parameter . "</td>";
        echo "      <td>" . $row->parameter_name . "</td>";
        echo "      <td>" . $row->in_type . "</td>";
        echo "      <td>" . $row->is_mandatory . "</td>";
        echo "      <td>" . $row->arg_1 . "</td>";
        echo "      <td>" . $row->arg_2 . "</td>";
        echo "  </tr>";
    }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: you got my question wrong @chunter i wanted the parameter name only in seprate row